# Show that the distribution of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i^2-3)$ is normal

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, convergence

Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be i.i.d. variables with $\mathbb{E}[X_i]=0$ and $\mathbb{V}[X_i]=3$ and assume that $\mathbb{E}[X^4_i]<\infty$, show that

$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i^2-3)
$$

follows a normal distribution.

Textbook says this is TRUE, but I don't see how. I can show that the quantity is bounded above by a normal (via delta method+fourth moment) or I can show that part of this quantity is normal (again by dm) but then the quantity $-\sqrt{N}3$ should always diverge.

Comment: This conclusion is not true.  I suspect you are omitting some crucial aspects of the textbook question, such as that this follows a standard Normal distribution *in the limit* as $n$ grows arbitrarily large.  Could you quote the text *exactly?*

Comment: This seems like a question that wants you to figure out aspects of the central limit theorem. The distribution of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i^2-3)$ is not *equal* to a normal distribution but will be as close as you wish to a normal distribution (for large $n$). .......... The point of the textbook question is that you are gonna *work* with the CLT. Where do the mean and the variance fit in (and also as a playfull twist you need to obtain the mean and variance of $X_i^2$ based on what is said about the moments of $X_i$)?

Answer (score 3):

This is not true in general, but as $n$ grows, the distribution of this random variable can be made as close as desired to normal, by the central limit theorem. Probably the author had in mind that for large values of $n,$ this can for practical purposes be taken to be normal.

Since $\operatorname E(X)=0$ you have $\operatorname{var}(X) = \operatorname E(X^2),$ so $\operatorname E(X^2)=3.$

And
$$
\frac{ \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i^2-\operatorname E(X_i^2))}{\operatorname{sd}\left(  \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i^2-\operatorname E(X_i^2))\right) } = \frac 1 {\operatorname{sd}(X_1) \sqrt n} \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i^2 - 3), 
$$
so the central limit theorem can then be applied.

The fact that $\operatorname E(X^4)<+\infty$ is used by seeing that it entails that $\operatorname{var}(X_1^2) < +\infty.$

To see that it's not *exactly* normal, consider the case were $X_i= \pm \sqrt 3,$ each with probability $1/2.$ You get a discrete distribution; hence not exactly a normal distribution.

Comment: That example which you give is a fun illustration but also it seems to be a trivial case; It has $E[X^4] =0$. You might say that the sum follows $$1/\sqrt {n} \sum_i ( X_i^2 - 3) \rightarrow \mathcal {N}(0,0) $$ And you may actually replace $\rightarrow $ by $\sim $. This makes 'not exactly normal' a complicated topic involving ideas about degenerate distributions and the meaning of $\mathcal {N}(0,0) $.

Comment: @MartijnWeterings : Where in the world did you get $\operatorname E(X^4) = 0 \text{ ?} \qquad$

Comment: $X^2 =3 $ it has only a single value. But I see now that indeed the central moments are zero and the raw moment is not. But anyway it still holds that (if you allow a normal with zero variance) you could say $$1/\sqrt {n} \sum_i ( X_i^2 - 3) \rightarrow \mathcal {N}(0,0)$$ because it depends on the moments of $X_i^2 -3$, which will be all zero.

Comment: @MartijnWeterings : What is given is that $\operatorname E(X^2)=3,$ not that $X^2$ is constantly equal to $3.$ And if it were, that would make $\operatorname E(X^4) = 3^4,$ not $0. \qquad $

Comment: @MartijnWeterings : Correction: It would mean $\operatorname E(X^4) = 3^2.$ At any rate, it is not consistent with the given information to say that $X$ is constant. Somehow you became confused about that. $\qquad$

Comment: Yes $X $ is not constant, but on the other hand $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i^2-3)$ *is* constant because $X_i^2$ is constant (it is always equal to 3). You do not just get a discrete distribution, but more specifically you get a degenerate distribution.

Comment: @MartijnWeterings : You're wrong: There is no reason to think $X_i^2$ is constant. If $X$ has expectation $0$ and $X^2$ has expectation $3,$ then $X^2$ would be constant only if $X=\pm\sqrt3,$ each with probability $1/2.$ But there are many probability distributions of random variables having expectation $0,$ variance $3,$ and finite fourth moment. In particular, one of those is the normal distribution with $\mu=0$ and $\sigma^2= 3,$ and for that distribution, $X^2$ is certainly not constant. You're only demonstrating that you are confused.

Comment: I agree with that Michael. But I was only speaking about <<the example which you give>> (which might be seen as the trivial case and is actually always a Normal distribution when you allow $\sigma=0$). That's the only thing I wanted to say with my first post (Hey, your example is actually a constant). You are right, if we generalize, then instead of saying that just the mean and variance of $X_i^2-3$ is zero we should require that *all* moments need to be higher.

Comment: @MartijnWeterings : But the example that I give does not have $\operatorname E(X^4) = 0;$ it has $\operatorname E(X^4) = 3^2 = 9. \qquad$

Comment: @MartijnWeterings : oh: You're saying the fourth CENTRAL moment is $0.$

Comment: Yes that's what I was supposed to say. I had it wrong in my first comment but corrected it in the second. But maybe I should not at all have mentioned the moments. My keypoint was just that your particular example is actually a degenerate distribution (a more specific case than a discrete distribution) and could be seen as *equal* to a normal distribution (already for $n=1$) when you accept $\sigma =0$.

Answer (score 1):

according to Lindeberg-Levy CLT 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem

let $ S_n = \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n X_k}{n}$

> Suppose {X1, X2, …} is a sequence of i.i.d. random variables with E[Xi] = µ and Var[Xi] = σ2 < ∞. Then as n approaches infinity, the random variables √n(Sn − µ) converge in distribution to a normal N(0,σ2)

${\displaystyle {\sqrt {n}}\left(S_{n}-\mu \right)\ {\xrightarrow {d}}\ N\left(0,\sigma ^{2}\right).} $

---

so let's mark $X_i^2 = Y_i$
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i^2-3) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^n(Y_i-3)= \sqrt{n}(\sum_{i=1}^nY_i-3)$$
now let's show that $EY_i = 3$ and $VarY_i = 1$

$VarX_i = EX_i^2 - E^2X_i => EY_i = EX_i^2 = VarX_i + E^2X_i = 3$

$VarY_i = VarX_i^2 = EX_i^4 - E^2X_i^2 = EX_i^4 - 9 < \infty$

thus

$$\sqrt{n}(\sum_{i=1}^nY_i-3)\xrightarrow {d} N(0, VarY_i)$$